# Multiple attachments for each record of table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Before I have tried about doing one attachment (upload) for each record of my table with using sql server and ASP.NET.
Now I like to do multiple attachments (uploads) for each record. Now I don't know what changes I have to do to my database and ASP.NET.
Some explanation or article or sample about that will be very helpful.
Best regards.

Comment: Have you got any sample code/sql server queries you could post, that we could suggest modifications to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowing for an infinite number of attachments, you're best out splitting those into another table and putting a foreign key on your parent table.

So, assuming this is your main table and fields

```
ITEM:
ItemId (Primary Key),
Description
etc,
```

Then you should probably create a second table to hold all the attachments, that way you can potentially 0 or 100s of attachments for each item. The Attachment table would be like:

```
ATTACHMENT:
AttachmentId (Primary Key),
File,
Description,
ItemId (Foreign Key to Item),
etc.
```

This way to find all attachments for an Item you could just query the Attachment table based on the Foreign key of Item, like so:

```
SELECT * From Attachment
Where ItemId = 'Current Item Id'
```